Selected day becomes blank when adding another iteration of field
First iteration of fields
Second iteration of fields
Following iterations with the same behavior
Every time I add an iteration of fields, the select field (el-select:ElementPlus) and its previously selected item becomes blank.
Code:
<el-form-item>
  <template v-for="(day, index) in gateForm.availableDays" :key="index">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 5px; margin-bottom: 0.5rem">
          <el-select v-model="gateForm.availableDays[index].day" placeholder="Day" value-key="dayId">
              <el-option
                v-for="availableDay in filterAvailableDays"
                :key="availableDay.dayId"
                :label="availableDay.dayName"
                :value="availableDay"
              />
          </el-select>
          <el-time-select
              v-model="gateForm.availableDays[index].timeStart"
              isRange
              placeholder="Start Time"
          />
          <el-time-select
              v-model="gateForm.availableDays[index].timeEnd"
              isRange
              placeholder="End Time"
          />
          <el-button type="primary" @click="addAvailableDays" :disabled="disablePlusButton"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></el-button>
          <el-button type="danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i></el-button>
      </div>
  </template>
</el-form-item>

data() {
return{
  gateForm: {
    gateId: "",
    name: "",
    status: "",
    remarks: "",
    siteId: "",
    availableDays: [
      {
        day: {
            dayId: null,
            dayName: ""
        },
        timeStart: "",
        timeEnd: "",
      },
    ],
  },
  availableDays: [
    { dayId: 1, dayName: "Monday" },
    { dayId: 2, dayName: "Tuesday" },
    { dayId: 3, dayName: "Wednesday" },
    { dayId: 4, dayName: "Thursday" },
    { dayId: 5, dayName: "Friday" },
    { dayId: 6, dayName: "Saturday" },
    { dayId: 0, dayName: "Sunday" },
    ],
  }
  },
computed: {
    filterAvailableDays() {
      return this.availableDays.filter((day) => {
        return!this.gateForm.availableDays.some((availableDay) => {
          return availableDay.day.dayId === day.dayId;
        });
      });
    },
    isRowComplete() {
      return this.gateForm.availableDays.every((day) => {
        return day.day && day.timeStart && day.timeEnd;
      });
    },
    disablePlusButton() {
        return this.gateForm.availableDays.length === this.availableDays.length || !this.isRowComplete;
    
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async addGate() {
      this.gateDialogFormVisible = true;
    },
    addAvailableDays() {
      console.log("gateForm", this.gateForm);
      this.gateForm.availableDays.push({
        day: {
          dayId: null,
          dayName: ""
        },
        timeStart: "",
        timeEnd: "",
      });
    },
  },

I am expecting it to be the same as the time select wherein it still shows the previous time selected even though I added iterations of the fields.

Don't use the index as a :key. What does your iterated-on object loos like? Inspect it using the Vue devtools to see why it is blank. You probably missed a small detail regarding the iteration of the value for the input.

Problem exists in using v-for="availableDay in filterAvailableDays", when an availableDay becomes filtered, it no longer becomes available to be displayed.  It's ok for one select, but second select causes others to rerender and thats when they find no option that matches it's v-model causing them to become blank.
